# is String(byte[], charset) memory efficient

Tags: java, android, string, memory-management, android-volley

I am looking at the source code for `Volley`, a java networking library for android, and it puts an entire network response into a new String object using the constructor `new String(byte[], String)`

where the bulk of the network response is a `byte[]` and the headers parsed as a string.

Is creating a large string this way memory efficient? I've seen network calls where `InputStream`s are converted to `String`s in a while loop and it can crash an application with when the application runs out of memory.

Comment: A String takes as much storage as a String takes.  You've presumably already got the `byte[]` array and the String literal to identify the character set, so there's not really anything else.  (What did you think might happen?)  (The worst thing to do is to create a String by repeatedly appending small pieces together.  That can run the garbage collector ragged.)

Comment: `A String takes as much storage as a String takes.` what if there isn't enough sequential memory available, does it accomodate that scenario on its own?

Comment: Your response is not megabytes long, is it? If it's only a few KBs, then the string will only be a few KBs as well.

Comment: If there isn't enough contiguous memory available (a) you're terribly memory constrained or have an enormous string, and (b) GC will run to attempt to free up storage so the String can be created.  The String will require that much contiguous storage regardless of how it's created.

Comment: @JBNizet I've had to deal with network responses that were megabytes long in the past, and I want to understand if this networking library can handle that.

Comment: @HotLicks in mobile development the developer is terribly memory constrained

Comment: I think an important question is to understand if each `byte` is getting blown up to `char`.

Comment: @pamphlet okay, I guess at this point I'll have to look at this string constructor's source code

Comment: Your JVM must have enough heap storage to manage the largest transfer, or else you must somehow arrange to write the data to disk or whatever so that not so much heap is needed.

Comment: If you have to download large responses, on a phone, and the networking library holds everything in a String in memory, then you should indeed consider another library, or handle those large files differently, by streaming them to disk directly. To answer the question, yes, each byte (or sequence of bytes) representing a character will of course lead to one char of the String.

Comment: @CQM - I do iPhone development.  "Terribly memory constrained" does not describe an iPhone or Android device.

Comment: Are the bytes representing characters? I just assumed it was converting binary data into a string for some reason.

Comment: The string decoder uses a float to indicated the char:byte ratio, so in theory it could support two bytes to a char. (Looking at StringCoding$StringDecoder class in Java 1.6).

Comment: It is true that a "smart" app would avoid converting `byte[]` to String if it wasn't necessary, to save both the heap use and the time involved.  But the ability to do that depends on what the data represents.

Comment: Generally I want my networking layer to let me read stuff straight out of its buffers.

Comment: @pamphlet: it all depends on the charset, and on the actual received chars. If the encoding is ASCII, every byte will translate to a character. If it's UTF8 but only contains chars in the ASCII range, you'll also have 1 char for 1 byte. If it's UTF8 and only receive chinese characters, you'll have 2 or 3 bytes (AFAIK) for each char.

Comment: @HotLicks I've encountered vast differences in how Iphone and Android devices handle loading 4+ megabyte network responses into memory. Stream parsing with something like GSON is very important at this size for android. So seeing a networking library that attempts to load an entire response into memory makes me pause

Comment: @JBNizet, yes I understand. But that only applies if the data is being sent using a character protocol (e.g. JSON, XML, etc., correct? A charset doesn't apply to an arbitrary binary data stream (or am I missing something?).

Comment: If what you're receiving is an arbitrary binary stream, calling the constructor doesn't make any sense. Binary data shouldn't be read as a String, but as bytes. And similarly, if you're calling the constructor with UTF8 as the charset and the chars are actually encoded using another encoding, you'll not get anything correct.

Comment: Exactly! So when OP says "the bulk of the network is response is a byte[] [but the whole response is being converted to a String]", it makes me wonder what's going on.

Comment: @pamphlet the library returns a "NetworkResponse" object named response. In its default configuration it then puts the response in a string constructor `new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say efficient compared to what, so your question doesn't really have an answer, but overall I agree with you. The response body after the headers should be made available as an input stream. It could be infinitely long after all. Reading entire requests or responses (or files) into memory is poor practice, and not 'efficient' by several measures, for example memory usage and latency.

Comment: That's a comment.  It doesn't answer the question "Is creating a large String using `new String(byte[], String)` efficient?"  Instead it's answering the question not asked, which is "Is it wise to receive a large data transfer and convert it to a single String rather than to write it to disk piecemeal or otherwise process it in parts?"

Comment: @HotLicks My final sentence answered the question, but I've revised it to make that clearer.